# It's the [20m-questions-milestone] but, I believe it should be gone

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I was looking through the tags list just to look at any random tags that could be deleted and I found the [20m-questions-milestone](/questions/tagged/20m-questions-milestone) tag.

Do we REALLY need it?

Some uhh questions:

(2 for 1) **1: Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? 2: Is it unambiguous?**

- Yes.
- Yep.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

- Not meaningful; little info. (Basically, no.)

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

- Yes

***B U R N*** IT!

Comment: More on topic: Care to state your case in arguments, and not just with assertions of "yes"? I highly doubt the request will fly well with just that.

Comment: Does it matter anywhere near as much? It's a meta tag, not a main tag.

Comment: I know but it's useless.

Comment: *I was looking through the tags list just to look at any random tags that could be deleted* ... well, just don't do that.

Comment: @SirStopIt "useless" is not a criteria. Useless tags die on their own as no one uses them, those that do not aren't useless by definition. If you are looking for something to burn, feel free to choose one of the 65412 tags on main that really need to burn and make a request. But whatever you do, please comply with the burnination process, i.e.: the tag must fail *all four* criteria and *actively cause harm*. We are not jumping around as tag-burning vigilantes - there is a due process for that. Also please make sure to support your request with reasoning as to why a tag needs to be burned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the burnination request *may* have merits otherwise, in its current state I cannot condone it.

First, it ignores the definitive criteria for making burnination requests (citing [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/11407695)):

> A tag must fail **ALL of those tests** in order to be considered for burnination. In any case, the ultimate criterion for burnination is whether the tag is actually causing harm

You answered "yes" to 3 out of 4 questions that are used to determine **whether the tag is OK**, not the other way around. Think of the 4 burnination questions as unit tests for burning tags.

Second, note the "ultimate criterion": does the tag *really* cause so much harm as to warrant a burnination request? Does not seem like it at all: it is not misused, it does not attract low-quality posts en masse, it just... exists. Just let it be.

Comment: The faq is unreasonable. Tags have to be useful, not merely just not cause harm.

Comment: @Braiam I know you'd say that :) But this is a discussion for another time - there are enough tags out there that cause active harm to burn - there is no need to loosen the grip on what is considered an acceptable burnination request. If you want to rediscuss the process, feel free to gather support for changing the process. But until then we should all follow what's due. Not to mention that far from everyone agrees we should gleefully burn anything just because it is not especially useful.

Comment: No, I prefer not waiting for them to cause harm. And I will discuss it every time, because we shouldn't allow such argument to set in. The help center has to win this argument every time: you should only create new tags when you feel **you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic** that nobody else has asked about before on this site. This tag doesn't pass that hurdle.

Comment: @Braiam I am not inclined to make this a discussion of your idea of how things should work. I strongly disagree that destructive actions should be easier to perform than constructive ones, and your quoting of the help center about *creating* new tags bears no significance in a discussion about *deleting* tags. If you feel the need the need to burn the tag - feel free to make a proper burnination request according to the current FAQ and stand scrutiny for the request. As I mentioned, if you want to change the process - gather support for changing it.

Comment: @OlegValter So many of us "love" that 5 minute limit... Perhaps that should be changed. I'll remove it though, cheers.

Comment: @SolarMike true that... I'll live with the shame of the typo to preserve continuity if you do not mind :)